# Bug: Add Comment Link JavaScript Error on Some Answers

Tags: bug, status-norepro, javascript, comments

I noticed a JavaScript error on the "Add Comment" link for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785764/asp-net-control-events-not-firing-inside-repeater/2242432#2242432). I've never seen the behavior on any other answer before, but clicking the link produces the following error in Firebug:

```
w.find("textarea").charCounter is not a function 
var vote=function(){var l={informModerat...t.documentElement.scrollTop}}})(jQuery);
```

Because of the error the comment frame never displays and a comment cannot be posted.

**Update**

Sorry I didn't mention it initially... I receive the error in Firefox 3.5.7. I do not receive the error in Chrome or Internet Explorer 8.

**Update 2**

Whatever the problem was, it has ceased now when I click that link. I have seen it approximately once more since I initially reported the issue, but it has been several weeks. If I see it again I'll update this post.

Comment: Huh, works fine for me in IE7. Why is there a `...` in there?

Comment: no-repro here, unfortunately.

Comment: Works on my machine/platform/browser.

Comment: @mmyers: I copied the truncated output from Firebug.

Comment: No-repro WinXP/FF 3.6

Comment: It's behaving for me in FF 3.57 on Windows 7. I'll do some more tests on my work computer tomorrow and see if I can figure out what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no repro. Have you tried disabling all Firefox extensions / running in "safe mode"